# Anyway I could change my OS Build?

Tags: windows-10, operating-systems, windows-subsystem-for-linux

My windows 10 computer has os build 10240, and I need higher for Windows Subsystem for Linux but I have used it before but I performed a factory reset. Please help.

Comment: Start > Settings > Update & security > Windows Update, and utilize the `Check for updates` button.  Once it installs the latest Window 10 Feature Update, you will be all set.

Comment: If you performed a Reset, and you had WSL installed, then you can’t be running the build you say you are because WSL wasn’t even a beta feature until a year after 1507 was released.  How did you determine you were running 10240 exactly?

Comment: @Ramhound I assume he means like a manufacturer's recovery to factory option/bootable media

Comment: If you update Windows to the latest build through Windows update it might be take a longer time to check if update and download and installing update. Or it will not make sure you could update to the latest Windows 10 1803. But if you search for "downlaod Windows 10 disc image" and use utility tool from this Microsoft website, it will update your system to the latest Windows 10 1803 more fast.

Answer (score 3):

"Build" is another term for "update level". So, update your computer. Build 10240 is the very first release of Windows 10, also called version 1507.

Windows Subsystem for Linux was released in build 16299 (version 1709).

Windows 10 is currently at build 17134, or version 1803.

The way you get updated version is to open Settings > Updates and Security> Windows Update.

Unless you have a compelling reason not to, you SHOULD be installing all Windows updates, including the feature releases.

Answer (score 2):

The build you currently have (10240) is Windows 10 version 1507, which is the very first Windows 10 release and is obviously very old. And (as @music2myear pointed out) you should really always try to be on the most recent release and have all Windows Updates.

**Windows Subsystem for Linux** (WSL) was first available to install in Windows 10 version **1607** (aka *Anniversary Update*, or build *14393*) but was really fully implemented in the *Fall Creators Update* (version **1709**, or build *16299*.) The current Windows version is version **1803** (aka as *April 2018 Update* or build *17134*.)

To bring your system up-to-date (which will allow you to use WSL) there are two ways (the first one is a bit simpler, but it could more often run into issues, certainly so if you have a Windows 10 that was never updated):

1. Open **Settings** > **Update & Security** > **Windows Update** and click **Check for updates**
2. Go to the **[Download Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10)** webpage and click on the blue **Update now** button to download the ***Update Assistant tool***. Run it and select the **Upgrade this PC now** option